# app does not appear under cellular data ios7

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios5, ios7

Under "App > Settings > Cellular Data"  my application doesn't appear under “Use Cellular Date For” on the iPad.Can anybody help me fix this?
MoreOver it should be defaulted to off.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. My iPad App is not listing under "Cellular Data". How can i show my App under that. My App want to use the Cellular Data too.

Answer (score 3):

It only adds apps when you use them to connect using 3G (cellular).

- Turn off your wifi while you are doing this
- then go into the app that you want to see in cellular data
- go back into the setting, cellular and scroll down

you should see the app listed.

You should also remember to turn your wifi back on.

Comment: given just launching the app is enough for it to use data.

Answer (score 0):

I have an app that use internet only via system. I mean iCloud and iCloud Keychain. There is no network code in it. And as far as I tested it never appears in this list though it does synchronise data when wi-fi turned off.

Answer (score 0):

From what i found is that, the app will only appear on the list, if it has used data. So switch of your wifi and force the app to use some data. In my case i had to send an email in the outlook app which was not appearing in the list under cellular data. Once i sent and dowloaded an email it appeared.